# Boost Graphs - ensuring deterministic graph behaviour

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-graph

I'm creating graphs from data from a JSON file and I'd like it so that when I traverse through both edges and vertices (e.g. in_edges(), vertices() or topological_sort() ) of the graph, it's in the exact same order regardless of the insertion order. In other words, to produce the same graph even if I shuffle the order of the JSON.

What would be the best way to do this? I'm currently using VecS as my Vertex and Edge types - would switching to SetS achieve this?

I'm currently thinking about using a wrapper struct around VertexDescriptors and EdgeDescriptors and also a wrapper class around a boost graph so that I can iterate over the graph internally, and return a sorted ordering of the Vertex/EdgeDescriptor wrapper struct instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really show any examples, so let me dream up an example, and how I'd probably parse these.

Let the following JSON documents represent the same graphs:

```json
{ "vertices": [
    {"name": "Cinderella", "id": 0},
    {"name": "Luke Skywalker", "id": 1},
    {"name": "Aurora", "id": 2},
    {"name": "Darth Vader", "id": 3},
    {"name": "Belle", "id": 4},
    {"name": "Han Solo", "id": 5},
    {"name": "Elsa", "id": 6},
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", "id": 7},
    {"name": "Rumpelstiltskin", "id": 8},
    {"name": "Princess Leia", "id": 9} ],
  "edges": [
        [0, 1], [0, 5],
        [1, 0], [1, 2],
        [2, 3], [2, 7],
        [3, 4], [3, 8],
        [4, 5], [4, 9],
        [5, 2], [5, 6],
        [6, 3], [6, 7],
        [7, 4], [7, 8],
        [8, 1], [8, 9],
        [9, 0], [9, 6]
    ]
}
```

And then flipping all possible properties at random and re-ordering the array elements at random, reformatting strings to contain escapes etc.:

```json
{ "edges": [
        [2, 7], [8, 9], [6, 3], [1, 0], [4, 5], [9, 6],
        [4, 9], [3, 8], [7, 8], [0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 4],
        [1, 2], [5, 2], [9, 0], [2, 3], [6, 7], [0, 5], [8, 1] ],
  "vertices": [
        {"id": 9, "name": "Princess L\u0065ia"},
        {"id": 8, "name": "Rump\u0065lstiltskin"},
        {"id": 5, "name": "Han Solo"},
        {"name": "Luk\u0065 Skywalker", "id": 1},
        {"name": "Bell\u0065", "id": 4},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Aurora"},
        {"id": 7, "name": "Obi-Wan K\u0065nobi"},
        {"id": 0, "name": "C\u0069nderella"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Darth V\u0061der"},
        {"id": 6, "name": "Elsa"}
    ]
}
```

I'd propose a helper function to build equivalent graphs from those documents:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
auto BuildGraph(json::value const& doc) {
    struct VertexProperty { std::string name; };
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperty> g;

    using Edge = std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t>;

    for (auto [s, t] : value_to<std::set<Edge>>(doc.at("edges")))
        add_edge(s, t, g);

    for (auto& v : doc.at("vertices").as_array()) {
        auto id = v.at("id").as_int64();
        g[id].name = v.at("name").as_string();
    }
    return g;
}
```

For now, I've assumed simple vertex ids `[0, numvertices)`. Note how the edges are sorted in a `set<>` before adding them to the graph.

Here's the combined listing showing equivalence after building the adjacency list:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019378c2ae0048bf)**

```cpp
#include <boost/json.hpp>
namespace json = boost::json;

auto doc1 = json::parse(
    R"( {
  "vertices": [
    {"name": "Cinderella", "id": 0},
    {"name": "Luke Skywalker", "id": 1},
    {"name": "Aurora", "id": 2},
    {"name": "Darth Vader", "id": 3},
    {"name": "Belle", "id": 4},
    {"name": "Han Solo", "id": 5},
    {"name": "Elsa", "id": 6},
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", "id": 7},
    {"name": "Rumpelstiltskin", "id": 8},
    {"name": "Princess Leia", "id": 9}
  ],
  "edges": [
    [0, 1], [0, 5],
    [1, 0], [1, 2],
    [2, 3], [2, 7],
    [3, 4], [3, 8],
    [4, 5], [4, 9],
    [5, 2], [5, 6],
    [6, 3], [6, 7],
    [7, 4], [7, 8],
    [8, 1], [8, 9],
    [9, 0], [9, 6]
  ]
})");

auto doc2 = json::parse(
    R"( {
  "edges": [
    [2, 7], [8, 9], [6, 3], [1, 0], [4, 5], [9, 6],
    [4, 9], [3, 8], [7, 8], [0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 4],
    [1, 2], [5, 2], [9, 0], [2, 3], [6, 7], [0, 5], [8, 1] ],
  "vertices": [
    {"id": 9, "name": "Princess L\u0065ia"},
    {"id": 8, "name": "Rump\u0065lstiltskin"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Han Solo"},
    {"name": "Luk\u0065 Skywalker", "id": 1},
    {"name": "Bell\u0065", "id": 4},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Aurora"},
    {"id": 7, "name": "Obi-Wan K\u0065nobi"},
    {"id": 0, "name": "C\u0069nderella"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Darth V\u0061der"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Elsa"}
  ]
})");

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
auto BuildGraph(json::value const& doc) {
    struct VertexProperty { std::string name; };
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperty> g;

    using Edge = std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t>;

    for (auto [s, t] : value_to<std::set<Edge>>(doc.at("edges")))
        add_edge(s, t, g);

    for (auto& v : doc.at("vertices").as_array()) {
        auto id = v.at("id").as_int64();
        g[id].name = v.at("name").as_string();
    }
    return g;
}

// For demo output
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename... Ts>
static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, boost::adjacency_list<Ts...> const& g) {
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<Ts...>;
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    auto n  = boost::make_function_property_map<V>([&g](V v) { return quoted(g[v].name); });
    print_graph(g, n, os);
    return os;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << doc1 << "\n\n";
    std::cout << doc2 << "\n\n";
    std::cout << (doc1 == doc2 ? "EQUAL" : "DIFFERENT") << "\n";

    auto g1 = BuildGraph(doc1);
    auto g2 = BuildGraph(doc2);

    std::cout << g1 << "\n\n";
    std::cout << g2 << "\n\n";

    auto s1 = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g1);
    auto s2 = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g2);
    std::cout << (s1 == s2 ? "EQUAL" : "DIFFERENT") << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
{"vertices":[{"name":"Cinderella","id":0},{"name":"Luke Skywalker","id":1},{"name":"Aurora","id":2},{"name":"Darth Vader","id":3},{"name":"Belle","id":4},{"name":"Han Solo","id":5},{"name":"Elsa","id":6},{"name":"Obi-Wan Kenobi","id":7},{"name":"Rumpelstiltskin","id":8},{"name":"Princess Leia","id":9}],"edges":[[0,1],[0,5],[1,0],[1,2],[2,3],[2,7],[3,4],[3,8],[4,5],[4,9],[5,2],[5,6],[6,3],[6,7],[7,4],[7,8],[8,1],[8,9],[9,0],[9,6]]}

{"edges":[[2,7],[8,9],[6,3],[1,0],[4,5],[9,6],[4,9],[3,8],[7,8],[0,1],[3,4],[5,6],[7,4],[1,2],[5,2],[9,0],[2,3],[6,7],[0,5],[8,1]],"vertices":[{"id":9,"name":"Princess Leia"},{"id":8,"name":"Rumpelstiltskin"},{"id":5,"name":"Han Solo"},{"name":"Luke Skywalker","id":1},{"name":"Belle","id":4},{"id":2,"name":"Aurora"},{"id":7,"name":"Obi-Wan Kenobi"},{"id":0,"name":"Cinderella"},{"id":3,"name":"Darth Vader"},{"id":6,"name":"Elsa"}]}

DIFFERENT
"Cinderella" --> "Luke Skywalker" "Han Solo" 
"Luke Skywalker" --> "Cinderella" "Aurora" 
"Aurora" --> "Darth Vader" "Obi-Wan Kenobi" 
"Darth Vader" --> "Belle" "Rumpelstiltskin" 
"Belle" --> "Han Solo" "Princess Leia" 
"Han Solo" --> "Aurora" "Elsa" 
"Elsa" --> "Darth Vader" "Obi-Wan Kenobi" 
"Obi-Wan Kenobi" --> "Belle" "Rumpelstiltskin" 
"Rumpelstiltskin" --> "Luke Skywalker" "Princess Leia" 
"Princess Leia" --> "Cinderella" "Elsa" 


"Cinderella" --> "Luke Skywalker" "Han Solo" 
"Luke Skywalker" --> "Cinderella" "Aurora" 
"Aurora" --> "Darth Vader" "Obi-Wan Kenobi" 
"Darth Vader" --> "Belle" "Rumpelstiltskin" 
"Belle" --> "Han Solo" "Princess Leia" 
"Han Solo" --> "Aurora" "Elsa" 
"Elsa" --> "Darth Vader" "Obi-Wan Kenobi" 
"Obi-Wan Kenobi" --> "Belle" "Rumpelstiltskin" 
"Rumpelstiltskin" --> "Luke Skywalker" "Princess Leia" 
"Princess Leia" --> "Cinderella" "Elsa" 


EQUAL
```

Comment: what if we don't assume the simple vertex ids?

Comment: It stays the same conceptually but slightly more tedious in others (explicit add_vertex). I'm not showing it for lack of clear target/example data

Comment: This is the most general/naive approach https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f8f7b2edae6b68, but many variations may exist. If you make the question more focused in the future, we won't have to guess things and can actually tailor code to your problem.

Comment: Essentially, every JSON has an ID (numerical, unique but not necessarily consecutive) and a list of ID's that represent it's parents. I want to always traverse the graph vertices from lowest ID to highest and the graph vertices from lowest source ID to highest and if equal then lowest target ID to highest.

Comment: You'll have to post a question with example inputs, because I don't see how "a JSON has an ID". Right now your comment more or less suggests the graph is _between various JSON documents_ and you just want to topologically sort those (much like a build tool would order dependencies)

Comment: Edited with example inputs

Comment: Probably best as a new question, because right now the edit seems to invalidate the existing answer. Will look tomorrow